# SMB share fstab entry won't mount but same options with 'mount' command will mount

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I'm running into some problems when mounting my SMB share using the `/etc/fstab` file.
Mounting the share with the `mount` command works just fine:

```
    mount -t cifs //hostname/dir /mnt/dir -o  user=myUser,pass=myPass,
ro,file_mode=0777,domain=mydomain.hh,_netdev
```

But when I try to create an entry in the `fstab` file:

```
//hostname/dir   /mnt/dir cifs    user=myUser,pass=myPass,ro,file_mode=0777,domain=mydomain.hh,_netdev      0       0
```

it does not mount during boot.
Do you guys have any idea? I'm on Linux 3.6.9 on an ARM Processor and the mount command is from busybox 1.21.

Comment: I put a script in  `/etc/network/if-up.d/`  so it would run when the network is up. this works, but I thought the `_netdev` option would do this?

Comment: (1) Do `mount //hostname/dir` and `mount /mnt/dir` work?  (2) Do the other entries in `/etc/fstab` (the ones that successfully mount at boot time) have `auto` in the options field (`user=…,pass=…,ro,…`)?  Try adding that to this one.